# How do I embed YouTube video channel in a web page?

Tags: html, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I have just integrated the below YouTube embedded code

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/.....">
</param>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/....." type="application/x-shockwave-flash"   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" width="560" height="340"></embed>
</object>
```

But I also want to list my video channel on my web page. How I can do this?

Answer (score -1):

try this: include this script tag where you want in you page
modifiy YourChannelName to your youtube name and the width and height of the iframe if you want

```
<script 
src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=YourChannelName&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js">
</script>
```

Comment: Dear i want separate list of channel look like on youtube site.

Comment: I can't get this to work.  Do I only need this script tag or do I need to do anything with html at all?  Do I need an iframe?  Will the channel page simply show wherever this script is?  You left out the biggest step, how to link this to the html.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison You should include the script wherever you want in the page and it will be replaced by the embed (read the first sentence of my answer). But the bigger problem is that my answer is 11 years old now and the link is dead. so this solution no longer works.