# Embed a Youtube Channel into HTML with iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to embed a Youtube channel into a HTML page.

For example I take this channel address: http://www.youtube.com/aaaa

I used this code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/aaaa"></iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. I tried with another site, and it works. What can be the problem?

Comment: Referring you to a similar question answered by me on stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212370/how-do-i-embed-youtube-video-channel-in-a-web-page/14671448#14671448

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I embed YouTube video channel in a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212370/how-do-i-embed-youtube-video-channel-in-a-web-page)

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be induced by this URL:http://www.youtube.com/aaaa.

I tried some other URLs and it works.

You can try some URLs easily [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe).

---

Try this:

```
  <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=aaaa&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

Comment: I edited my answer.That works if you uploaded your own videos.
If you want to share playlist, just use embed code provided by Youtube.

Comment: This is better, works. But I would like to can press Subscribe button without opening a new tab...

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do that.Maybe this tool can help you.
http://www.widgetbox.com/widgets/make?code=youtube

Comment: This works fine. But interface is ugly. Is there any way direct to youtube ? this goes over google modules.

Comment: The answer is missing the html that is the placeholder for the iframe in the page.  This will not work with just a script tag.  I need some kind of html that the script tag sends the info to.  Please fix the answer.  It is unusable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/aaaa" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

This was taken from youtube [here](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html)

it appears IE (and others) can only use [youtube.com /embed/ videoID] (HTML5 Player) - at least the way I am implementing them.

Comment: it appears IE (and others) can only use [youtube.com /embed/ videoID] (HTML5 Player) - at least the way I am implementing them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```html
<div name="iframe" style="width:100%; height:635px; border:2px solid grey; overflow:hidden">
  <iframe src="http://yourchannel-URL" style="width:100%; height:700px; margin-top: -65px" scrolling="true">
     If you can see this, your browser doesn't support iframes. Click <a href="http://mychannel.url">here to see my YouTube channel.</a>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

This should embed a complete youtube channel without a youtube search bar.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work for me. It appears only a border and a line inside of it. Nothing more. Maybe you find another solution.

Comment: It's does not work

Answer (score -3):

To display a gallery of thumbnails of your YouTube Channel's most recent videos, you can use an iframe:

```
<iframe
    onload="javascript:this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';"
    scrolling="no"
    height="600"
    marginheight="0"
    frameborder="0"
    width="480"
    src="http://youtubechannelembed.com/gallery.php?vids=9&user=doitfordummies&row=3&width=150&margin_right=15&desc=100&title=30&views=1&likes=1&dislikes=1&fav=1">
</iframe>
```

Comment: The domain you have linked to here appears to appears to have been taken over by some scam site.