# How to Embed YouTube Channel with an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

There's plenty of guides on how to add YouTube channels by username. I've discovered you can add YouTube channels via an iFrame using code like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=YOURCHANNELNAME" width="480" height="400"></iframe>
```

However, this only works if the channel name is extracted from a URL like this:

https://www.youtube.com/user/YOURCHANNELNAME

How can I embed channels that don't have "user" in the URL, like this one:

https://www.youtube.com/freecodecamp

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add all the videos of the channel so I would suggest you to share the whole playlist of all videos.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3zw5LgKDMhg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Also you don't have to view their channel only by `yt.com/freecodecamp`, you can also have this one - `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ/`that has /channel inside of it.

So I would check [this link](https://techblog.dorogin.com/how-to-embed-youtube-channel-player-36058a2c7001) because it could be useful and you can find information you need over there :)

EDIT:
There's also a topic on Stackoverflow with the similar problem and there's an answer that might help you - [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040181/embed-a-youtube-channel-into-html-with-iframe)