# How to embed a youtube channel in my site in 2022?

Tags: html, jquery, youtube, embed

I've been looking for information for days and haven't found anything that works for me.

I am trying to place an entire youtube channel on one of the pages of my website.

I have found other solutions like:

> [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209217/how-to-embed-a-youtube-channel-into-a-webpage)
>
> [Solution 2 (spanish forum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301196/embedding-most-recent-youtube-video-with-channel-id)
>
> [Solution 3 (spanish forum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135393/how-to-embed-youtube-channel-with-an-iframe)

But none of them worked for me or they are too old.

Comment: How did they not work for you?

Comment: @Geshode When you enter the code and the channel id, nothing is displayed, it comes out blank. If you have managed to make it work could you explain me how? thanks

Comment: @Sara11 provide the channel you want to embed. Not sure why you added "spanish forum" - I don't see spanish on those links...